# Evaluating $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I thought the improper integral $\int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx$ converge, while the textbook says it's not.
Of course, $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function. Here is my solution:

---

For any $n\in \mathbb N$,$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=n\;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\; n\leq x<n+1 $$

Thus if $\; N\leq t<N+1$
$$\begin{align}&\int_{1}^{N}\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx\leq\int_{1}^{t}\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx\leq\int_{1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx\\
&\Rightarrow \;\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n!}\leq\int_{1}^{t}\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx \leq\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}\end{align}$$
Taking $N\rightarrow\infty$ both sides also gives $t\rightarrow\infty$, and we have
$$e-1\leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx \leq e-1$$
Therefore, $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor!}dx=e-1$. □

---

I've tried a sort of times to find some mistakes in what I wrote. But I didn't get anything till now. 
Can somebody point out what I missed? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it converges. Are you sure your textbook says that it does not ?

Comment: Your work is very correct  $\to +1$

Comment: So: either a mistake in the the textbook, or the OP  miscopied the problem here.  Since the identity of the textbook is secret, no one here can verify this.

Comment: Thank you guys all! Later I will call the author to verify it.

Answer (score 7):

Setting
$$
I=[1,\infty), \quad I_n=[n,n+1) \quad \forall n\ge1,
$$
we have
$$
I=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n, \quad I_j\cap I_k=\varnothing \quad \forall j\ne k.
$$
Since
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor =n \quad \forall x \in I_n, \quad n=1,2,3, \ldots
$$
it follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\lfloor x\rfloor !}
&=&\int_I\frac{dx}{\lfloor x \rfloor ! }\cr
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{I_n}\frac{dx}{\lfloor x \rfloor !}\cr
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{I_n}\frac{dx}{n!}\cr
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1-n}{n!}\cr
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\cr
&=&-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\cr
&=& e-1.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{1}^{∞} \frac{1}{\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor !} dx&=\lim_{N \to ∞}\lim_{λ_{max} \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{λ_{i}}{\left \lfloor x_{i} \right \rfloor !} \\
&=\lim_{N \to ∞} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n!} \\
&=e-1.
\end{aligned}
$$